# Let constructor change object type

Tags: c#, constructor

My code is using a list with baseclasses that i later cast into their respective derived types. I hit a point where I thought I could create a constructor for the baseclass that would figure out of what type it should be and change itself into that type. Something like this:

```
    public class BaseClass
    {
        // Constructor
        BaseClass(string Input)
        {
            if (Input.Substring(0, 5) == "Something")
                return new DerivedClass(); // <-- Not allowed
        }
    }
    public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
    }
```

This isn't allowed since a constructor must return void. Changing type of "this" doesn't seem to be allowed either. I know that there are very simple alternatives to this code that works, but I think that it has a certain elegance to it, don't you think?

Comment: A constructor that constructs something else, that should be elegant??

Comment: Yeah you can't `return` anything from a constructor in C#. The result of a `new` is always a concrete instance of that type. You need to use a factory to do this. A factory is just a function that decides which derived type to create and returns it.

Comment: Wow, you are quick! My point was not to look for ways to code this but more as a discussion of the language itself. Am I the only one that find this approach intuitive?

Comment: @RagnarDa: This isn't a discussion site; it's a QA site, so the posters are going to provide answers on how to code what you're trying to do. Whether it's elegant or intuitive is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look into the Factory Pattern. It is used when you want to create an instance of an object but allow the specific type to be determined based on other parameters.

```
public static class BaseClassFactory
{
    public static BaseClass Create(string input)
    {
        if (input.Substring(0, 5) == "Something")
            return new DerivedClass();

        return new BaseClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, a SingleTon is too heavyweight.

Answer (score 3):

I would also recommend the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) but write it differently.  This prevents the creation of BaseClass with `new`, so the only option to get a class is through the `Create` method.

```
public class BaseClass
{
  private BaseClass()
  {
  }

  public static BaseClass Create(string input)
  {
    if (input.Substring(0, 5) == "Something")
      return new DerivedClass();

    return new BaseClass();
  }
}
```

Comment: does not compute. non-static constructor in static class.

Comment: For some reason I thought what you have now is what the OA (original answerer?) had posted. That's why I was baffled by the static class. But his is static. Anyway +1 for this pattern (factories as static methods of base classes). Works great in abstract classes too!